# when I run this for the first time, it worked well. but now it doesn't. i want to add 'is' if the current string doesn't contain is'' in beginning

Tags: python, string, list

[image]

```
def convert(string):
   li = list(string. Split(" "))
   return li
str1 = input("insert string: ")
x = convert(str1)
print(x)
if x[0] == "Is":
    print("unchanged string : " + str1)
else:
    a = "Is"
    y = [a] + x
    str2 = " ".join([`str`(element) for element in y])

    print(str2)
```

Comment: Your issue is that you want to handle lowercase `"is"` at the start of the string?

Comment: ```if x[0].lower() == "is":``` <-- Correct. yours is case sensitive. When you enter ```is```, it is obviously not equal to ```Is```. Hence, it added the new ```Is```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: The problem is that "Is" and "is" are different as other has an upper case "I" and later has a lower case "i".

If you want to have both cases covered, you can change compared strings into lower cases like this

`if x[0].lower() == "Is".lower():`

ps. Overall your code has some parts confusing pars and I don't think those need to be addressed here, but you could avoid some of the confusions by not using "string" as a name for a parameter or a variable for example.

Comment: In my example I lower cased the "Is" as I think that it shows the thinking behind this solution. Not as it couldn't be converted just to "is". As I think this is more on the level of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.lower()` function. So even if it is capital or small it is ok.

Code:-

```
def convert(string):
   li = list(string.split(" "))
   return li
   
str1 = input("insert string: ")
x = convert(str1)
print(x)

if x[0].lower() == "is":
    print("unchanged string : " + str1)
else:
    a = "Is"
    y = [a] + x
    str2 = " ".join([str(element) for element in y])

    print(str2)
```

Output:-

```
insert string:  is it ok
['is', 'it', 'ok']
unchanged string : is it ok
```

Comment: no. it's not the case. when I insert a string without "is' in the beginning, program supposed to convert string into a list and then insert 'is' in the beginning of the list and then convert the list into a string. also if the string i insert contains 'is' in the beginning, the program supposed to convert the string into a list and then check if it contains 'is' in the 0 index position, if yes, print the string unchanged.

Comment: Yes, that what the code I posted says. It check the same as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `is` is not case sensitive this code will do what you want.

Also you don't need to do this: `str2 = " ".join([str(elem) for elem in y])` as the contents of list `y` are all of type `str`.

Just `join` them without converting them to `str` like this: `str2 = " ".join(y)`

```
def convert(string):
   li = list(string.split(" "))
   return li

str1 = input("insert string: ")
x = convert(str1)
print(x)
if x[0].lower() == 'is':
    print("unchanged string : " + str1)
else:
    a = "Is"
    y = [a] + x
    str2 = " ".join(y)

    print(str2)
```

```
Output

insert string: he good
['he', 'good']
Is he good

insert string: is he good
['is', 'he', 'good']
unchanged string : is he good

insert string: Is he good
['Is', 'he', 'good']
unchanged string : Is he good
```

Comment: @KaveeshaFernando If you like my answer please upvote and accept as answer. Thanks!